# Videos lag after inverting screen (with xrandr -o inverted)

Tags: video, rotate

After inverting screen (with "xrandr -o inverted"), videos lag : it is like if the lower third of the screen doesn't refresh at the same time than the higher 2 thirds of the screen.

This doesn't occur when the screen is normal, not rotated.
And it doesn't happen on Windows 10.

I searched in "Additional drivers", but nothing appeared.

Do you know how this could be fixed?
Thanks in advance.